# Batch Login Code

Tags: batch-file, authentication

Sorry for the big essay im just trying to give details on how this is supposed to work.

I've been working on a login code and ive made it so when you run the .bat it asks if you want to register or login. The registration works fine. It creates a text file called whatever the username is. So if you type the username "User1" it will create a new text file called "User1.txt". After that it asks to input a password 2 times to make sure you type it correctly. Once you type the password in both times it will save the password inside of the "User1.txt" file so now you have a password inside of "User1.txt"

```
:Register
set /p User=Enter A Username: %=%

IF EXIST %User%.txt (

call :colorEcho c %User%
call :colorEcho c " Already Exists."
echo.
call :colorEcho c "Please Choose A Different Username."
echo.

goto Register
) ELSE (
set /p Pass=Enter A Password: %=%
set /p RePass=Re-Enter Password: %=%
)

if %RePass%==%Pass% goto RegFinal
if not %RePass%==%Pass%(
call :colorEcho C "Passwords Do Not Match"
echo.
goto Register
)

:RegFinal
echo %Pass%>%User%.txt
echo Welcome %User%
pause
exit
```

The problem im having is with the login. I have created 2 users with the register function from above. Username-r1 Password-p1 and username-r2 password-p2. If i login it will ask for your user and password. i enter r1 and p1 and it goes to the incorrect login screen. i type r1 and p1 again and it shows the welcome screen. Also if i type r1 and p1 in it loops back to :login because it thinks its the wrong user/password. but when i go to input the user and password in again i can either use r2 and p1 or r2 and leave the password blank and it will let me into r2 with p1 and even a blank password

```
:Login
set /p User=Enter Your Username: %=%

IF EXIST %User%.txt (
set /p Pass=Enter Your Password: %=%

>nul findstr /c:%Pass% %User%.txt && (
echo Welcome %User%
) || (
echo Incorrect Username or Password
goto Login
)

) ELSE (
call :colorEcho c %User%
call :colorEcho c " Does Not Exists."
echo.
goto Choice
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You see, the answer is simple. You should: A: Refrain from using call, unless you have a file saved with extra data that needs called, B: get rid of the %=%, as the set /p command allows you to type and submit your choice without using extra sub-commands, C: try adding a menu before logging in, that should be like this:
(where you have to type something, before it put: echo Please enter a [user/pass], also the login bit I added has to be edited where it says 
if not %username% == * goto LOGINERROR and if not %password% == * goto LOGINERROR by adding what you want your username/password to be where the * is. I added that as the main feature of your code, so you can log in without fail, and your register feature as a way for other people using what ever you make this code out to be to make an account temporarily without having to use yours. Feel free to edit this code at will and redistribute it any way you want, as there should be no code breaking bugs. Hope you and everyone who views this learns something new about batch coding, as it took me hours to get my code on this site to where it can be copied/pasted as is. Enjoy!)

```
@echo off
cls
:loop
cls
:menu
echo Greetings, what will you do?
echo.
echo 1.) Login
echo 2.) Register
echo 3.) Exit

set /p cho=

if %cho% == 1 goto loginfile
if %cho% == 2 goto Register
if %cho% == 3 exit

if not defined variable (
goto loop
)

:Register
cls
set /p User=Enter A Username: %=%

IF EXIST %User%.txt (

call :colorEcho c %User%
call :colorEcho c " Already Exists."
echo.
call :colorEcho c "Please Choose A Different Username."
echo.

goto Register
) ELSE (
set /p Pass=Enter A Password: %=%
set /p RePass=Re-Enter Password: %=%
)

if %RePass%==%Pass% goto RegFinal
if not %RePass%==%Pass%(
call :colorEcho C "Passwords Do Not Match"
echo.
goto Register
)

:RegFinal
cls
echo %Pass%>%User%.txt
echo Welcome %User%
pause
goto mainmenutwo

:looptwo
:loginfile
cls
echo Which file will you login in as?
echo.
echo 1.) Save 1

set /p save=

if %save% == 1 goto LOGIN 1

if not defined variable (
goto looptwo
)

:LOGIN 1
cls
echo ------------------------------------------------
echo                       Login
echo ------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo.
set /p "username=>"
set /p "password=>"

if not %username% ==  goto LOGINGERROR
if not %password% ==  goto LOGINGERROR

goto mainmenutwo

:LOGINERROR
echo ------------------------------------------------
echo                     Error
echo ------------------------------------------------
echo Invalid Username or password
pause
goto LOGIN 1

:loopthree
cls
:mainmenutwo
```